# WHERE IN sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find which items in WHERE IN clause do not exist in the database. in below example cc33 does not exist and I need the query to give back cc33.
how would I do that ?

```
SELECT id FROM tblList WHERE field1 IN ('aa11','bb22','cc33')
```

Comment: will you have multiple ID for each field1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the values into a table rather than a list:

```
with list as (
    select 'aa11' as val union all
    select 'bb22' union all
    select 'cc33'
)
select l.val
from list l left outer join
     tbllist t 
     on l.val = t.field1
where t.field1 is null
```

Comment: Why not `SELECT COALESCE(t.id, l.val)`? (+1 anyway)

Comment: I was going to do 3 separate JOINs. This is much better.  And even without CTE we can have UNION as sub-query with the same logic.

Comment: @zerkms . .. The `where` statement is explicitly checking that all the values on `t` are NULL.  Such a coalesce would be at best redundant and at worst cause a type conflict when `id` and `val` are of different types.

Comment: both answers work. Which one would have better performance ? These aa11, bb22 are just test values, I'm going to put here thousands of them

Comment: @pirmasnaujas . . . The performance is probably going to be fast enough either way.  Here is a reference that says that the `NOT IN` gives better performance (http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/).  Note that the case studied is much larger and includes duplicates.  If performance really matters, you should test it on your data.

Comment: I had to change your query a little bit, because my old sql2000 would not accept WITH clause. Anyway here is how it works in it:     `select l.val
from (
    select 'aa11' as val union all
    select 'bb22' union all
    select 'cc33'
) l left outer join
     tbllist t 
     on l.val = t.field1
where t.field1 is null`

Answer (score 3):

For SQl-Server versions of 2008+, you can use a **[Table Value Constructor:](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)**

```
SELECT field1
FROM
  ( VALUES
     ('aa11'),('bb22'),('cc33')
  ) AS x (field1)
WHERE field1 NOT IN
      ( SELECT field1 FROM tblList ) ;
```

Tested at **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/05e45/3)**

Comment: this query is also working, but I could not make it work in sql2000

Comment: Yes, it was added in 2008 version. It won't work in 2000 or 2005 versions.

Comment: For previous versions, you'll have to stick with the `UNION` version that Gordon answered.